# Create menu with angular-materials

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-material, materialize

I have the following menu made with materializeCss but a friend recommended to use angular-material, examples of angular material there is one similar to mine and I have not been able to reproduce because the menu is dynamically created according to user permissions.
I appreciate if you can tell me how it's done

[image]

Comment: How what is done? Question is too broad. Narrow it down to specifics and show the code you have problems with

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860471/how-to-add-checkbox-to-angular-menu How to add checkbox to angular menu please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest way of doing it For right section: you can use JSON in your controller such as

```
$scope.jsonTest=[

 {
   imagePath:"",
   title:"",
   userPermission:["admin","superAdmin"] 
 },
 {
   imagePath:"",
   title:"",
   userPermission:["admin"] 
 }
];
```

and in your html file

you can use

```
<div ng-repeat="item in jsonTest" >

   <div ng-show="item.indexof(userRole) > 0">
       ....(display content)
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I refer is the html part, so as to create menus, will tell you that the logo on the left and right buttons.
In materializeCss is added `<nav><div ng-controller="dashboardController" class="nav-wrapper light-blue darken-4"><a href="#" class="brand-logo"><img src="img/Logo.png" alt="Inicio" width=75 height=60 class="left" />Gastos de Viaje</a><a href="#" data-activates="mobile"`
but not as would put those positions with angular-materials

Comment: try to use flex and align attributes