# How to add checkbox to angular menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

[My menu looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i001.jpg) . I have a worker menu which specifies the list of menu items .just the names alone.I would like to add a checkbox for selection before the menu text.[I would like to add a checkbox in menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQyID.jpg) 
    Any help is much appreciated

```
<pre> $scope.workerMenu = [
            {
                description: vocabulary.scope.worker.header.menu.apples,
                action: function () {
                    displayWorkerProfile();
                }
            },
            {
                description: vocabulary.scope.worker.header.menu.oranges,
                action: function () {
                    validateDeletion()
                }
            }
        ]</pre>
```

Comment: Don't add comments to augment the question. You can [edit] the question instead.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14521482/1309377